# If I use webview at Android, do I have to apply SSL to loading URL on webview?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-security, google-play-console

I got a warning message when I published my App to Google Play Store. 
It's about  **"JavaScript interface injection issue"**

I think I should apply SSL to URL to solve this problem.
But, I cannot apply SSL to URL... that's out of my hand.

Is there any way I can solve it?

**My app’s min sdk 17** and **targetsdk 27.**

Comment: So your WebView displays a html page that contains an http:// link. Where does the web page come from?

Comment: @Robert The web page come from our company. but They aren't modifying the web page any more.

Comment: OK, then it is not a technical problem you can solve. Tell them that willful ignorance comes at a price, the price that your app is dead because of them and you will loose customers/money because of them. Also write this in a letter to your upper management and see what happens ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a technical but an organizationally problem of the company the app belongs to.

Comment: I agree with your opinion .Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Link here.
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config#CleartextTrafficPermitted

Hope this will help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

If you provide https to URL. then you will change cleartextTrafficPermitted attribute to "false".